# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^ne^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

I was trying to compute the value of the definite integral

$$\ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^ne^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx$$

I noticed that the Gamma function would be particularly relevant here, since after all

$$\Gamma(n+1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x}dx$$

To obtain something that resembles the Gamma function, I divided the fraction by $\ e^{2x}$

$$\ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^ne^{-x}}{e^{-2x}+1}dx$$

And then noticed that

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}} = 1 - e^{-2x} + e^{-4x} - e^{-6x} + e^{-8x} ..... $$

Evaluating each term, we get:

$$\ I = \int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-x}dx - \int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-3x}dx + \int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-5x}dx - \int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-7x}dx.....$$

$$\ I = n! - \frac{n!}{3^n} + \frac{n!}{5^n} - \frac{n!}{7^n}..... = n!\cdot (1-\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^n} -\frac{1}{7^n}.....)$$

This immediately reminded me of the Riemann Zeta function, but I am unable to express the final result in terms of it. I know that

$$\ 1 +\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^n}+\frac{1}{7^n}+\dots = \zeta(n) - \frac{1}{2^n}\zeta(n)$$

But I was unable to find the alternating difference, which is the expression in the final result. Can someone please help me with that? Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think you just derived https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function.

Comment: @BobDobbs Whoa, thanks! That's cool, didn't know about this. These special functions sure are handy things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my older [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168722/21783) should help here (as in Bob Dobbs' comment) :
\begin{align} I(m):=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^m}{2\,\cosh(t)}dt&=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^m\;e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}dt\\ &=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\;t^m\;e^{-(2k+1)t}\;dt\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^m}\int_0^\infty u^m\;e^{-u}\frac{du}{2k+1}\;\\ &=\Gamma(m+1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^{m+1}}\\ &=\Gamma(m+1)\,\beta(m+1)\\ \end{align}

where $\beta$ is the [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Comment: Whoa, thanks a lot! Your answer looks very unexpected, wouldn't expect such a complicated integral to evaluate into such a nice looking integer!

Comment: Let's be honest you found it yourself :-) and just needed a correct term for the alternating series! Excellent continuation anyway, (for the reader I used the substitution $\,u:=(2k+1)\,t$)

Comment: Believe me, I didn't.  The truth is, I was actually studying the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos(ln(tanx))dx$. When you substitute $\ tanx = t$ and then $\ lnt = u$, followed by some rearranging, we get the integral of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^xcos(x)}{e^{2x}+1}dx$. Then I was merely playing around, putting the Taylor series of cos(x) about 0 into the integral, and that led me to thinking about integrals of the form $\frac{x^ne^x}{e^{2x}+1}$.

Comment: In my [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168722/21783) I indicate too $\displaystyle \frac 1{\cosh(t)}=\int_0^\infty \frac {\cos(t\,x)}{\cosh(\pi\,x/2)}\;dx$ that should help you to simplify your $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^xcos(x)}{e^{2x}+1}dx\,$ formula! You may too try directly [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%28cos%28x%29%2Fcosh%28x%29%2Cx%3D0..infinity%29)

Comment: Do you mind sharing your thoughts [on this follow-up question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830616/fascinating-property-of-the-dirichlet-beta-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For a direct derivation you could use the relation $(7)$ from [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html) between $\beta(2n+1)$ and the Euler number $E_{2n}$ : $$(-1)^n\beta(2n+1)=\frac{ E_{2n}}{2(2n)!}\left(\frac {\pi}2\right)^{2n+1}$$ and conclude with the $E_n$ [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers) at $t=\frac{\pi}2$ (the odd terms being $0$) : $$\frac 1{\cosh t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {E_n}{n!}t^n$$ Answering yourself is fine! Cheers,

Comment: As indicated by X-Rui $\beta(n)$'s limit is $1$ so that this is rather a formal derivation using generating functions (i.e. not requiring convergence). A better idea could be to study the limit as $\;\displaystyle t\to \frac {\pi}2, t<\frac {\pi}2$