# Fascinating property of the Dirichlet Beta function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions

I was originally investigating the definite integral

$$\ I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos(\ln(\tan x))dx$$

After substituting $\ln(\tan x) = u$ and changing the upper and lower bounds, the integral simplified into

$$\ I =  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos u \cdot e^u}{1+e^{2u}}du$$

Which is nothing else but

$$\ I = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos u}{\cosh u} du$$

Now, I considered the Maclaurin series of $\cos x$:

$$ \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Then, I substituted this summation inside the integral:

\begin{align}
 I 
&=  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^u}{1+e^{2u}} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot \frac{u^{2n}}{(2n)!} du \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^u}{1+e^{2u}}du - \frac{1}{2!}\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^2e^u}{1+e^{2u}}du + \frac{1}{4!} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^4e^u}{1+e^{2u}}du +\ldots 
\end{align}

Rearranging the terms, we get:

$$ I  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^{2n}e^u}{1+e^{2u}} du $$

As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830561/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracxnexe2x1dx) and substituting $\ 2n$ instead of $\ n$, we get:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^{2n}e^u}{1+e^{2u}} du = \Gamma(2n+1)\beta(2n+1) = (2n)!\beta(2n+1)$$

Substituting this equality into our original integral, note that the $(2n)!$ terms cancel and we obtain

$$\ I = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\beta(2n+1)$$

Meanwhile, from the comments in the answer of the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830561/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracxnexe2x1dx), setting $\ t =1$, we have:
$$\ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos u}{\cosh u} du = \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \operatorname{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Then, is it valid to assert the below equality?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\beta(2n+1) = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \operatorname{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Which seems to be true, [as per WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summation+n+%3D+0+to+inf+%28-1%29%5En*%28DirichletBeta%5B2n%2B1%5D%29) at least.

Can we derive it via any other method? The sum on the LHS feels like a daunting one, but it turns out to be equal to this rather simplified expression on the right.

Also - as pointed out in the comments, the limit as k approaches ${\infty}$ of $\beta(2k+1)$ should be $\ 1$. Given that this is true, how do we explain the fact that this sum converges?

Thank you for reading. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. At least according to desmos.

Comment: Be careful after your first substitution, the bounds aren't right, since $\ln(tanx) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$, it shouldn't make any difference to the calculation, though, since it is an even function.

Comment: @GTBailey Yes, the bounds are from ${-\infty}$ to $0$, which should yield the same integral as from $0$ to ${\infty}$

Comment: I think I found your mistake. $I=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\cosh x}dx$ and not $2\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\cosh x}dx$

Comment: @KamalSaleh It is indeed equal. You can check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summation+n+%3D+0+to+inf+%28-1%29%5En*%28DirichletBeta%5B2n%2B1%5D%29)

Comment: You are right. Your link doesn't work but the complicated expression wolfram gives on my end seems to be the same as $\frac{\pi}4\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5DDirichletBeta%5C%2891%292k%2B1%5C%2893%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D

Comment: Now that your link works, it is interesting to see that our inputs give different results.

Comment: About formatting, common operators in LaTeX like $\cos$, $\ln$, and $\tan$ should be preceded by a backslash, i.e. $\verb|\cos|$, $\verb|\ln|$, and $\verb|\tan|$. Otherwise, you'll notice they get italicized like variables and become hard to distinguish.

Comment: I know little about Dirichlet beta but it seems it approaches 1. So strictly speaking your series diverges. However, it does seem to oscillate around $\frac{\pi}{4}\mathop{\rm sech}(\frac{\pi}{2})$, just like how $1-1+1-1+1-1+...$ does around $0.5$. See [this Wolfram|Alpha page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+%28pi%2F4%29%2Bsum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B9%7D%28%28%28-1%29%5Ek%29); you can try to vary the upper bound of the partial sum.

Comment: Mathematica confirms this form via the following command: `FullSimplify[Sum[(-1)^n DirichletBeta[2n+1],{n,0,\[Infinity]}]]`.

Comment: The Taylor series of hyperbolic secant is defined as $$\operatorname{sech}z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$$ where $E_n$ is the $n$th Euler number. In the present context, this leads to the identity $\beta(2n+1)=(-1)^n\dfrac{E_{2n}}{2(2n)!}(\pi/2)^{2n+1}$ which is attested on Mathworld (eq. 7 [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the story short, if you enjoy the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$ I = \int \cos(\ln(\tan x))dx$$
$$I=\frac{1+i}{4}\, \tan ^{1-i}(x) \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1-i}{2},1;\frac{3-i}{2};-
   \tan ^2(x)\right)+$$
$$\frac{1-i}{4} \tan ^{1+i}(x) \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1+i}{2},1;\frac{3+i}{2};-
   \tan ^2(x)\right)$$ which is defined for $(0 \leq x \lt \frac \pi 2)$

$$ J = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}  \cos(\ln(\tan x))dx$$
$$J=\frac 1 8\Bigg(\left(\psi\left(\frac{3+i}{4}\right)-\psi
  \left(\frac{3-i}{4}\right)\right)- \left(\psi \left(\frac{1+i}{4}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{1-i}{4}\right)\right) \Bigg)$$
$$J=\frac{\pi}{4} \  \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

It seems the answer is pretty straightforward if one has knowledge about the Taylor expansion of $\operatorname{sech(z)}$ and its relation to the Euler numbers.

We have:

$$\operatorname{sech(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!}\cdot z^{2n}$$

Also, as pointed out in the comments, it is known that

$$\beta(2k+1) = \frac{(-1)^k\cdot E_{2k}}{2(2k)!}(\frac{\pi}{2})^{2k+1}$$

Multiplying $(-1)^k$ on both sides and taking the sum from $\ n = 0$ to $\infty$, we get the final result:

$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\beta(2k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_{2k}}{2(2k)!}\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2})^{2k} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{E_{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2})^{2k} = \frac{\pi}{4} \operatorname{sech(\frac{\pi}{2})}$$

I also noticed that if we rearrange $\ (-1)^k\beta(2k+1)$ a little, it turns out to be a sum of infinite GPs. Then it becomes equal to the sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \beta(2k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{1+(2k+1)^2}$$

which does indeed converge to $\frac{\pi}{4}\operatorname{sech(\frac{\pi}{2})}$

But the doubt regarding whether the sum should converge, if at all, remains unresolved. I cannot think of a reason to justify its convergence if the limit as n approaches infinity of $\beta(2n+1)$ is $1$.

Comment: To put the final question another way: one formally has $$\frac{\pi}{4} \operatorname{sech}\frac{\pi x}{2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2k}\beta(2k+1).$$ What is the interval of convergence for this expansion? (The nearest singularities to $x=0$ in the complex plane are the poles at $x=\pm i$, so that would suggest that $|x|\leq 1$ is indeed the disk of convergence.) The issue is that convergence on the boundary can be fairly involved: see for instance the wikipedia discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Convergence_on_the_boundary).

Comment: My own interpretation would be that the convergence depends on the order of limits. If we take $x=1$, then $(-1)^n \beta(2n+1)$ does not converge to $0$ and hence the series (the sequence of partial sums) does not converge either. But if one restricts to $|x|<1$ and takes the limit $n\to\infty$, then one recovers the hyperbolic secant function. Only then is it valid to consider $x\to 1^-$. (This is the same kind of story one has for Grandi's series and the function $1/(1+x)$.)